# Unable to automatically sync Message Center posts to Microsoft Planner: please fix connection issue

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-planner

I am not able to automatically sync Message Center posts to Microsoft Planner and I am getting please fix a connection issue alert. Do you know why I am having this issue or if this is related to my license for power automation or power apps?[I have attached the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bv2w1.jpg)

Comment: Could you please check that your planner connection has expired?

Answer (score 0):

When the planner connection expires you cannot post answers. please check that your planner connection has expired

Comment: Actually, It looks like my account needed global read permisson setting